# Contradictory results while performing Z-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, z-test

Hello Everyone,
I'm relatively new to statistics and this community so please bear with me and forgive me if I commit any mistake while asking my question. For starters, here are two hypotheses tests that I want to perform:

Test 1: If on an average, Girls score more than 600 in an exam?
Test 2: Mean score of girls = 600.

**Given: sample mean(x) = 633.4, sample size(n) = 30, population std dev(σ) = 100**

So first I performed **Test 1** where (**null hypothesis(H0): mean<= 600)** and **(alternate hypothesis(H1): mean > 600)**.

**Z = (x – μ) / (σ / √n)** = (633.4-600)/(100/√30) = **1.83**.
Taking **alpha = 0.05** and since this is a **upper-tailed Z test**, the decision rule is: **Reject H0 if Z > 1.645**.
Hence, **we reject H0 and accept H1**. Therefore, **Girls score more than 600** in an exam.

Now, coming to **Test 2**
**H0: mean score = 600** and **H1: mean score != 600**

**Z = 1.83** and since this a **Two-Tailed Z Test**, the decision rule is: **Reject H0 if Z < -1.960 or if Z > 1.960**

**However, we fail to reject H0. Therefore, mean score = 600.**

**Please explain why the 2 tests are giving contradictory conclusions?**

Answer (score 0):

The test aren't giving contradictory results. You are in a sense using contradictory significance levels.

If you want to require equivalent "evidence" (I'm putting that in quotation marks, because p-values do not exactly assess evidence) in a "particular direction" (i.e. in the "is higher" or "is lower" direction), then one uses one-sided tests with half of the significance level of two-sided tests. I.e. if you use a two-sided test for $\alpha = 0.05$, then the one-sided test would use $\alpha = 0.025$. If one does so, then the significance threshold for the test statistic is at $\pm 1.96$ in both cases.

Or, to put it in other words, in your example you suddenly say that in the one-sided case you are willing to tolerate a twice as large type I error rate in the "greater than"-direction under the null hypothesis as you were willing to tolerate in the two-sided case.

Comment: Umm do you mind showing it mathematically so that the results match? That would be a great help!!

Comment: How do you mean other than 0.05 / 2 = 0.025? The 2.5th / 97.5th percentile of a standard normal distribution is then $\approx \pm 1.96$, while the 5th/95th ones are $\approx \pm 1.65$. Another way to look at it: You get the two-sided t-test for mean = 600 at the 0.05 level by doing two one-sided t-tests (one for the < 600 alternative and one for the > 600 alternative) at the 0.025 level and rejecting the null hypothesis of mean = 0 when either of the two one-sided tests has rejected its null hypothesis.